# Symfony , get the real SQL requests executed by flush

Tags: symfony, entitymanager, flush

I'm curious to know if there's any method to get the SQL request executed by flush(), for example:

```
$manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$Person = new Person();
$Person->setName("Wajdi");
$Person->setAge(25);
$manager->persist($Person);
$manager->flush(); ///<--------
```

I need to get something like that:

```
Insert into person("name","age")values("Wajdi",25);
```

Any ideas ? Thank you !!

Comment: You need it *in code* or just to debug something? Using the symfony toolbar, you can see all executed queries. There's also an option to `"View runnable query"`.

Comment: Thank you, I forget about that !!! :)